# Space in Textangular editor 1.5.1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textangular

I'm using Textangular 1.5.1, I have this string inside:

```
<p>            MyText</p><p>              MyText2</p>
```

But Textangular show the text without the spaces:

```
MyText
MyText2
```

The only way is using the: `"&nbsp;"`, but I don't want to replace all my spaces "" to `"&nbsp;"`.

There is any workaround or Textangular offer any option to avoid the `"&nbsp;"`

Comment: May I suggest Froala editor instead of Textangular. It is much cleaner and in my opinion better. There is also a angular directive for it.

Comment: @Ohjay44 Thanks but I tested and the problem with the white space is the same we have to use &nbsp;